# How to enable NonChecked checkbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I am unchecking a disabled `Checkbox` using some code behind.

I need to enable this `Checkbox`  when it is unchecked and do it using XAML.

I do this

```
 <CheckBox Margin="10,320,427,0" Name="chkIsDefault" 
IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Self, Mode=OneWay}" 
 IsChecked="{Binding IsDefault, Mode=TwoWay}"     />
```

But it is not working. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to directly bind to another property of the same object use [`RelativeSource=Self`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.self(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<CheckBox ... IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

but since you want invert behaviour (disable when checked) you could modify binding to use custom `IValueConverter` but I would suggest to use a simple `Trigger` instead

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsDefault, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: From what I understand he will also need a converter because using this code as is he will get `IsEnabled=IsChecked=false`. I understand that if IsChecked == false, then IsEnabled must be true, therefore a converter is needed (assuming I get the question right ;))